# What is the difference between this->variable and namespace::class::variable in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, namespaces, this

Consider this:

I have a class with some private variables and some public methods e.g. setters or constructors. When I'm implementing the methods, does it make any difference to say `this->variable = 0;` or `namespace::class::variable = 0;`?

in header (example.h):

```
namespace spc
{
    class MyClass
    {
     public:
            MyClass();
     private:
            int variable;
            int variable2;
    };
}
```

now in the cpp file (example.cpp) I have:

```
spc::MyClass::MyClass()
{
     spc::MyClass::variable = 0;
     this->variable2 = 0;
}
```

This will compile. And also in the application source, constructing and object of this class will have both variables with value 0 (assuming I have some getters as well). So my question is: are these two lines of code any different from each?

Comment: Both are unnecessary.

Comment: So how do you assign a value to a member variable? By just saying 'variable=0;'?

Comment: Yes exactly, as long as you are within a member function or the variable is public

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This will compile

```
spc::MyClass::variable = 0;
this->variable2 = 0;
```

That's right! But this will also compile, producing the same result:

```
variable = 0;
variable2 = 0;
```

In general, `this->` and scope resolution `::` operator are there for you to instruct the compiler which variable to use when there is any ambiguity. For example, a constructor parameter may have the same name as a member variable:

```
spc::MyClass::MyClass(int variable2)
{
     this->variable2 = variable2;
}
```

Here, the use of `this->` differentiates between `variable2`-the-parameter and `variable2`-the-member of `spc::MyClass`.

In the absence of ambiguity, however, using "plain" variable names is "idiomatic" to the language.

**Note:** One difference between `MyClass::something` and `this->something` is when something is a virtual member function; the former will suppress the virtual call mechanism, while the later will not (thanks, Sebastian Redl, for a great comment).

Answer (score 3):

The following statements are equal:

```
spc::MyClass::MyClass()
{
    // Very uncommon
    spc::MyClass::variable = 0;

    // Use this for clarity, if you feel the need
    this->variable = 0;

    // Short and common
    variable = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this->variable` causes the name to be looked up within the scope of the current class.

`MyClass::variable` causes the name to be looked up within the scope of `MyClass`.

In this case, the current class is `MyClass`, so both are equivalent to an unqualified `variable`.

In other cases, they might not be. For example, `Base::member` might refer to a member of a base class while `this->member`, within a derived class's member function, might refer to a member of the derived class that hides the base-class member.